# Convergence of $u_{n+2}=\frac{(u_n+n\cdot u_{n+1})u_n}{(1+n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Considere a sequence $u$ where $u_0$ and $u_1$ are given us. For $n\ge 0$ Considere:

$u_{n+2}=\frac{(u_n+n\cdot u_{n+1})u_n}{(1+n)}$

Prove that this sequence converges (or not).

My attempt to solution:

I could not find all conditions to solve the problem. And I do not know how to continue.

$1)$ I started assuming that this sequence converges:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {u_n} = L$

So, $L = \frac{(L+n\cdot L)\cdot L}{(n+1)} => L(L-1) = 0 => L = 0$ or $L = 1$

If $\exists\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {u_n} $, it must be $0$ or $1$

$2)$ Now, I tried find some conditions to convergence:

Suppose that $u_0 = u_1 = 0$ this implies that $u_n = 0$ ,  $\forall n \ge 0 => L = 0$

Suppose that $u_0 = u_1 = 1$ this implies that $u_n = 1$ ,  $\forall n \ge 0 => L = 1$

Suppose that $u_0 , u_1 \in (0,1)$ this implies that sequence converges to $0$.

$3)$ Are so many cases and considerations that I could not find all the solutions, and I do not know if exist some theorem that help or some manipulation that make more easier. I tried for a long time, but I really could not resolve.

Comment: Empirically I suspect that for any $u_0$ in an interval such as  $(0,4.44299\ldots)$, there is a positive $u_1 < 5.5224137$ which leads to convergence to $1$, and for any non-negative $u_1$ less than this you get convergence to $0$ and for any $u_1$ greater than this you get divergence to $+\infty$